# Now() - Show Month and Day only - Microsoft Access

Tags: date, ms-access

When I use this function in Access: Now()  it returns this: 27-04-2012 10:03:09

How can I make a function that only show month and date like this: 27-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a function that will return the date in the format day-month, then you can do the following:

```
Public Function test()
    Dim testdate As String
    test = Format(Day(Now()), "00") & "-" & Format(Month(Now()), "00")
End Function

Result:
29-04
```

If you wanted to use the date format in a query, you could just do:

```
select (Format(Day(Now()), "00") & "-" & Format(Month(Now()), "00")) as DayMonth
From yourtable
```

or

```
select (Format(Now(), "dd-mm")) as DayMonth
From yourtable
```

Comment: @HansUp because I was half-asleep when I wrote it and wasn't thinking obviously. :) Updated to add that query.

Answer (score 2):

Example: a field in your table is DOB and then you need it to output only Day and Month only. So you need to choose data type Date/Time and then you should Format is where field properties and in general tab and then input like this: dd-mmmm

hope it can help you.

Comment: Cool that works in Access, but when I extract the date on my website, it shows with year, hour, minute and seconds :(

Comment: sorry i know only in access. but i think that when you extract the date on your website, maybe you should format it again.